# Two exercises. Exponential and Cauchy's distributions.

Tags: probability

Can anybody help me with two execrises ?

1. $X$ is random variable with exponential distribution ($\lambda =1$) i.e. $X \sim Exp (1)$. Find distribution of $\lfloor X \rfloor$ and $X - \lfloor X \rfloor $.
2. $X$ has Cauchy distribution, i.e. with density $g(x)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$. Prove that random variables $X$ and $Z=\frac{1}{X}$ have the same distributions.

About second exercise:
I calculated that $P(X \le t)=F_X(t)=\frac{\arctan t}{\pi} +\frac{1}{2}$. Now:
$P(Z \le t )= P \left(\frac{1}{X} \le t \right) = P \left(\frac{1}{t} \le X \right) = F_X(\infty) - F_{X-} \left( \frac{1}{t} \right) = \frac{1}{2}- \frac{ \arctan \left(\frac{1}{t} \right)}{\pi}$, and I'm confused, because of course  $ \frac{\arctan t}{\pi} +\frac{1}{2} \neq \frac{1}{2}- \frac{ \arctan \left(\frac{1}{t} \right)}{\pi}$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $\arctan (1/t) = \pi/2 - \arctan (t)$ I think... (at least for $0 \leq t\leq \pi/2$) draw a traingle to convince yourself.

Comment: Apart the fact that these two questions might belong to a common homework of yours, they are not related.

Comment: *Am I doing something wrong?* Yes, because $1/X\leqslant t$ is not always equivalent to $X\geqslant1/t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for the first part:

$\lfloor X\rfloor$ is a discrete random variable, so we just need

$P(\lfloor X\rfloor = n )=P(n \leq X <n+1)$

$Y = \lfloor X\rfloor - X$ is harder, but I think we can do

$ P(Y\in dt) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X - \lfloor X\rfloor \in dt |\lfloor X\rfloor = n )P(\lfloor X\rfloor = n )$

You just need to work out the conditional distribution, which shouldn't be too difficult, I think.